# How can I intentionally create a server error on apache to test error log

Tags: apache, logging, error-handling, server

I'm on network solutions apache server.  On their setup page I chose to enable error logging. Nothing ever seems to appear in the log folder though.  I suppose that could be good if I really have no errors.  How could I create an error that should show up in the log folder so I can test it.

Comment: Accessing non existing resource on server url?

Comment: I'm not experienced in this.  That would be a 404 error, right?  I heard 404's don't get put in the error log.

Comment: Yes, 404 is not getting logged. Try removing read permission of a file and accessing.

Comment: Excellent.  That was easy.  It created a 403 that got logged.  Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you know the answer to this also... I just tried to download the log file so I could view it.  It's saying I don't have permission to download it.  Any idea why I wouldn't have permission to download a log file?

Comment: Log file would be accessible by root  and admin (most probably ) group. If your user-id does not belong to group then you can not even view.  But if you are able to view/read on server then it should not be an issue.

Comment: very strange.  it's set to User read/write Group read/write.  Can't access it at all though

Answer (score 0):

If you have enabled dynamic scripts, how about a script that dies or won't compile?

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

die "This script intentionally produces HTTP 500";
```